# setting current date time in sharepoint form field (newform.aspx) sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, sharepoint-enterprise, list-form, date-time

I am working on customizing the sharepoint list form (newform.aspx). So soon as the user opens the new form I want the Odate coloumn (date and time) to be filled automatically with the current date and time and get disabled.  It is taking the current date but I am not sure how to set the time.  Below is the code, any suggestions?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var datinformat = date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
$("input[title ='Origin Date']").val(datinformat);

    $("input[title='Origin Date']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

[Update]:
[image]
Hi Eric, when i changed default value of the field to today
-It shows hour properly,but in the minutes section is shows 0 even 
if it is 15 mins or any number
- and from the image when when i change the setting of the date
 field to include the time as well from the image i got hour and mins
 dropdwn...but even if the Odate field is disable the hour and mins
 dropdown still remain selectable..any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

Can't you just set the default value for the field to be [Today]?

You'll also need to utilize the PreSaveAction to reenable the Odate column or it won't get saved. http://wael-abbas.blogspot.com/2009/02/sharepoint-presaveaction.html

Comment: Thank Eric for pointing me to the PreSaveAction.

Comment: Never heard about this function, but it's really useful, thanks

Comment: Me either but thanks for this savior action :D

Comment: Hi Eric, i have updated the question

Comment: The date and time fields are separate inputs so you'd have to disable those too.  And since they have predefined values, you can set those as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add the time to the string you are building?  The [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) has time methods as well...  You do have to make sure that the underlying field is DateTime and not simply Date as that will truncate the time back off when it saves